# Process cannot be killed in macOS

Tags: macos

I have a homebrew app called sshfs which sometimes hangs and that is not the worst.
Killing the process is NOT possible.

Pressing Ctrl+C in the terminal window where is is started leaves only ^C behind, but does not stop the process.
Closing the terminal windows does not stop the process either.
In another terminal I run `ps -ef | grep sshfs` to obtain the PID.
Running commands like `killall sshfs` or even `sudo killall sshfs` do not help. Neither do `kill -9 <pid>` with the pid of sshfs, even not when prepended with sudo to enforce running as root.

So I had to reboot and even `sudo reboot` is ignored after filling in the password.
So I had to hard switch off my Mac and restart (which is luckily rather quick).

It feels like back to the MS-DOS era ....

I run macOS Big Sur 10.16.3 on a Macbook Pro 2018.

Comment: What is the state of the process when it is unkellable? Run `ps ax|grep sshfs` to check.

Comment: `mypc:~/scratch % ps ax|grep sshfs
 6558   ??  Ss     0:00.02 sshfs user@host:/var/www/html /Users/user/remotefolder
 6564 s002  S+     0:00.00 grep sshfs
`
Using zsh on macOS connected to a Linux server but now it is in a 'normal' state, I can exit it normally.

Comment: Please run the command when the process can‘t be killed